# Construct CW complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

How can I construct a CW complex A with $H_0(A) = \mathbb{Z}$, $H_2(A) = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, $H_4(A) =
\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ and all other homology groups trivial? 
Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: could you give some motivation? is this a homework question? the only reason I would think it is HW is because of the way you have written it.

Answer (score 6):

Let $f:S^2\to S^2$ be a map of degree $4$. Attach a $3$-cell $B^3$ to $Y=S^2$ using $f$ to glue the boundary $\partial B^3=S^2$ to $Y$. Then $Z=Y\cup_f B^3$ has homology given by $$H_q(Z)=\begin{cases}
\mathbb Z, & \mbox{if }q=0; \\
\mathbb Z/\mathbb 4Z, & \mbox{if }q=2; \\
0, & \mbox{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Now consider the connected sum $Z\vee S^4\vee S^4$.

**NB:** The interesting part is of course the construction of $Z$. If I recall correctly, you can find in Hatcher's book information regarding *Moore spaces*, of which $Z$ is a simple example.